# How a .net Application can create a record in CRM contact table?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have an existing .net web application that creates Customer contact record in regular SQL Server Database. Now we are migrating to CRM.

I am wondering from the .NET web application, what is the procedure to talk to CRM server and create a Contact record?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As bjynito said, you want to look at the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb928212.aspx), espescially helpful when starting out will be the [Programming Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb887726.aspx)

Here is a sample of creating a contact from [a page in the programming ref.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928994.aspx)

```
// Set up the CRM Service.
CrmAuthenticationToken token = new CrmAuthenticationToken();
// You can use enums.cs from the SDK\Helpers folder to get the enumeration for Active Directory authentication.
token.AuthenticationType = 0; 
token.OrganizationName = "AdventureWorksCycle";

CrmService service = new CrmService();
service.Url = "http://<servername>:<port>/mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx";
service.CrmAuthenticationTokenValue = token;
service.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// Create the contact object.
contact contact = new contact();

// Create the properties for the contact object.
contact.firstname = "Jesper";
contact.lastname = "Aaberg";
contact.address1_line1 = "23 Market St.";
contact.address1_city = "Sammamish";
contact.address1_stateorprovince = "MT";
contact.address1_postalcode = "99999";
contact.donotbulkemail = new CrmBoolean();
contact.donotbulkemail.Value = true;

// Create the contact in Microsoft Dynamics CRM.
Guid contactGuid = service.Create(contact);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectionString = "Url=https://orgname.crm5.dynamics.com; Username=adminusername@damnidiot.onmicrosoft.com; Password=your  password;";   //configure this line 

            string value = "lllllllll";

            AttributeCollection at = new AttributeCollection();
            //at.Add("fullname",(String)value);
            at.Add("firstname", (String)"LLLL1");
            at.Add("lastname", (String)"ffff1");


            Entity ent = new Entity();
            ent.LogicalName = "contact";
            ent.Attributes=at;
            CrmConnection connection = CrmConnection.Parse(connectionString);
            OrganizationService organisationservice = new OrganizationService(connection);
            Guid g = organisationservice.Create(ent);

}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've misunderstood (or I have) - CRM = Contact Relationship Management but doesn't imply a particular server/architecture

eg I write CRM software that uses a SQL Server back-end. If you can provide more information, we may be able to help futher

Comment: It sounds like he's using Microsoft Dynamics CRM

Comment: Note to self check the bl00dy tags

Answer (score 0):

Recommend reading through the [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928212.aspx).  In particular, look at the articles on the web services and messages available.